# Start remote Jboss with Jenkins using JBoss plugin

Tags: jboss, jenkins

I'm trying to use the [JBoss plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin) on Jenkins to start and stop a remote Jboss.
Because there isn't documentation on the plugin page I'm not able to make it work.
When I set the parameters for the plugin I don't know what I have to put for the parameters:

```
Command to start server
Command to shutdown server
```

Do you ever used this?

Cheers